# JSP - How are names looked up (Tomcat/MVC)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, model-view-controller

I would like to know how exactly symbols are resolved in JSP-Files.

I have a very vague understanding of this entire topic, but i assume that this is not related to JSP itself but the surrounding environment:
In my case this is Java Spring MVC running on a Apache Tomcat-Server.

Quick example of what i mean: 
    div class="someUnknownType"

**Who** looks **where** for "someUnknownType" upon reaching this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the simple html elements.. they are rendered by the browser (our who). Before loading the page.. it loads the resources (stylesheets, etc) and subresources (defined in header).

So, once it reaches the line.. it knows where to check for which element (css file, js file, etc) depending on its type.

If you are talking about the elements in jsp (java code, jstl tags, etc).. they are rendered by the container (new who). Since required jars and source files are already loaded, it is not difficult to execute.

HTH

Comment: So i do not have to expect any complex XML-configuration that is somehow handled by Spring or whatever, etc.? Its basically just: If i want to use an identifier in HTML-context this identifier has to be declared somewhere within the page OR its included files (which are also included within the page), right?

Comment: Alright then, thank you for clarifying this, i now have a way clearer view on this.